# Jagged Array: Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I came across [this tutorial](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/arrays2.html) and was wondering why the Java compiler would throw an error for the last example. Could someone explain?

Here's the excerpt:

--

**Java Ugliness: Syntactic Irregularity and Ad Hoc Logic**

In this irregular but convenient syntax: `int[] v = {3,4};`, it does several things in one shot: {array type declaration, value assignment, number of elements declaration, slots fulfillment}. However, this syntactical idiosyncrasy cannot be used generally. For example, the following is a syntax error:

```
int[] v = new int[2];
v = {3, 4};
```

Here's a complete code you can try.

```
public class H {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] v = new int[2];
        v = {3,4};
        System.out.print(v[0]);
    }
}
```

The compiler error is: “`illegal start of expression`”.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "{}" brackets cannot be used *after* the array size has already been made. The code will not run because it tries to assign a size to an array that already has a size. To define the elements in the array after "int[] v = new int[2];", you must use "v[0] = 3;" and "v[1] = 4;"

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
public class H {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] v = {9,6}; // new array with default values
        System.out.print(v[0]);
        v = new int[]{3,4}; //note: this will create a new array
        System.out.print(v[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just simply against the syntax's rules. You can do either of the following for the same results.

1. `int[] v = {3, 4};`
2. `v[0] = 3; v[1] = 4;`